# How to ssh using JSch to ZXA10 C320 device

Tags: java, ssh, router, jsch

I am developing a Java application to ssh to a zxa10 c320 device. I used jsch library to ssh. But when I run the application its hold in the first while loop without returning any output. When I run this application by pointing to ssh some other Linux servers, it works properly.

Please advise me if I did anything wrong.

I try this in both 'exec' and 'shell' modes.

Also, I try to do this using sshj library. It also didn't work.

```
public class RunCommand {

    public String runCommand(String command) {
        String host = "XX.XX.X.XX";
        String user = "user";
        String password = "password";
        String result = "";

        try{
            Properties config = new Properties();
            config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
            JSch jsch = new JSch();

            // Create a JSch session to connect to the server
            Session session = jsch.getSession(user, host, 22);
            session.setPassword(password);
            session.setConfig(config);

            // Establish the connection
            session.connect();

            if(session.isConnected()) {
                System.out.println("Connected...");
            }

            ChannelExec channel = (ChannelExec) session.openChannel("exec");

            channel.setCommand("pwd");

            int stat = channel.getExitStatus();

            StringBuilder outputBuffer = new StringBuilder();
            StringBuilder errorBuffer = new StringBuilder();

            InputStream in = channel.getInputStream();
            InputStream err = channel.getExtInputStream();

            channel.setPty(true);
            channel.connect();

            System.out.println("Channel Connected");
            System.out.println("channel.isConnected() "+channel.isConnected());
            System.out.println("channel.isClosed() "+channel.isClosed());


            byte[] tmp = new byte[1024];
            while (true) {
                while (in.available() > 0) {
                    int i = in.read(tmp, 0, 1024);
                    if (i < 0) break;
                    outputBuffer.append(new String(tmp, 0, i));
                }
                while (err.available() > 0) {
                    int i = err.read(tmp, 0, 1024);
                    if (i < 0) break;
                    errorBuffer.append(new String(tmp, 0, i));
                }
                if (channel.isClosed()) {
                    if ((in.available() > 0) || (err.available() > 0)) continue; 
                    System.out.println("exit-status: " + channel.getExitStatus());
                    break;
                }
                try { 
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (Exception ee) {
                }
            }

            System.out.println("output: " + outputBuffer.toString());
            System.out.println("error: " + errorBuffer.toString());
            channel.disconnect();
            session.disconnect();
            System.out.println("Channel And Session Closed!!!");
        }catch(JSchException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            result = "Auth fail";
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: What if you remove the `channel.setPty(true);`?

Comment: Also, can you do `ssh user@host pwd`? (or `plink user@host pwd` - if you are on Windows).

Comment: Where does it block?

Comment: hi @MartinPrikryl i tried by removing channel.setPty(true). It also didn't work.

Comment: it's blocked when the in.available() get called. Seems in.available() not getting greater than 0.

Comment: You didn't answer my other question.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl when i tried to plink it gives an error. Error: Access granted. Please Return to begin session. FATAL ERROR: Server refused to start a shell/command

Comment: So can you execute the command using `ssh` or `plink` **automatically** (not by typing the command in an SSH terminal) anyhow? Until you can do that, there's no point trying to implement it in Java/JSch. What about `echo pwd| plink user@host`?

Comment: for the echo pwd| plink user@host it say connection is abandoned.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl the doubt which i have is,  if i can login and run commands by using putty. why can't i do that by jsch..

Comment: What about `echo pwd| plink -t user@host` or `echo pwd| plink -T user@host`?

Comment: For both commands  it say :                                                                            The first key-exchange algorithm supported by the server is
diffie-hellman-group1-sha1, which is below the configured warning threshold.
Continue with connection? (y/n) Connection abandoned.

Comment: Be more proactive please. -- Fix the warning and try again.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl when i tried to execute those commands without echo i was able to login from the windows command prompt

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't able to do this using peo java. But i was able to this using paramiko module of python. What i did is i wrote two applications one with java and one with python, then i call python application from java application and ssh to gpon by python application.